# How can I edit controls inside master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

In short i want to edit controls inside master page in .net framework from its content page during design time. This is because in content page during design time all master page controls are not accessible to content page my question is:
  how can i make all master page controls accessible to content page during design time?
is this possible or not?
Thanks in advance

Comment: wat do u mean by design time???

Comment: I mean in design mode in aspx  page for content page how can change attribute values to master page control using mouse?

Comment: y u want to change masterpage controls in content page ??

Comment: yes u can do it in code behind in c# in runtime rendering

Comment: but i can not in design time?

Comment: @AdelFahed : it's not possible as you say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't edit them in the derived page. It does not make sense. 
But you can edit them in master page in designer, and you can still change master page's control in derived page's codebehind at runtime.